# cakephp saving multiple rows

Tags: cakephp-2.4

I want add 11 rows in the table.

in view :

```
<?php echo $this->form->create('Detail',array('action'=>'add'));?> <fieldset>
  <legend>Add New Detail</legend><?php for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
  echo $this->form->input('Detail.$i.name');
  echo $this->form->input('Detail.$i.text');
  echo $this->form->input('Detail.$i.taille');
  echo $this->form->input('Detail.$i.police');
  echo $this->form->input('Detail.$i.bold');
  echo $this->form->input('Detail.$i.italic');

  echo $this->form->input('ticket_id');}?>
```

form->end('Submit');?>

in my controller DetailsController:

```
 public function add($count=1) {

  $tickets= $this->Detail->Ticket->find('list');
  pr($tickets);
  if($this->request->is('post')){
 $this->Detail->saveAll($this->request->data['Detail']);}     
     $this->set('tickets', $tickets);$this->set('count', $count);}
```

my problem is :
the code save 11 rows similar to the last input(
exp: in browser i add nom1 nom2 nom3 .. nom11
but in table: add 11 rows renamed nom11
)
I'am sorry my bad English language

Answer (score 1):

May be there is some issue with your fields name.
Try this may be this will work :-

```
<?php
  echo $this->form->create('Detail',array('action'=>'add'));
?> 
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Add New Detail</legend>
 <?php 
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
       echo $this->form->input("Detail.$i.name");
       echo $this->form->input("Detail.$i.text");
       echo $this->form->input("Detail.$i.taille");
       echo $this->form->input("Detail.$i.police");
       echo $this->form->input("Detail.$i.bold");
       echo $this->form->input('Detail.$i.italic');
       echo $this->form->input("ticket_id");
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: but 'ticket_id' foreing key it display 11 time.

Comment: i want ticket_id display for the all form

Comment: please change echo $this->form->input("ticket_id"); to echo $this->form->hidden("ticket_id"); and check

Comment: it's save 'ticket_id' at value 0

Comment: but I want to save at value 1

Comment: and this not worked      $this->form->hidden("ticket_id",array('value'=>'1');}
or     $this->form->hidden("ticket_id",array('value'=>1);}

Comment: can you please post your updated code in your question?